# How to forward an specific FTP User to a Honeypot?

Tags: linux, ftp, honeypot, shared-hosting

What I'm trying to do is to forward a specific FTP-User to a Honeypot, because the main server is for Shared Hosting and there's a lot of traffic, and I don't want to spend all the resources in monitoring users that I don't want to.

Is there a better way to obtain information of a Specific Shared Hosting User?

This is possible? The server is CentOS.

Comment: I'm confused about what you actually want to do. Why forward a set of users to a honeypot? Why not disable their accounts? Why do you want to monitor those accounts?

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you would need an FTP proxy which was capable of proxying to different actual FTP servers based on the username that was supplied.

[Frox](http://www.hollo.org/frox/) has this essential functionality; it can [route users](http://frox.sourceforge.net/doc/FAQ-1.html) when they use user@actual.ftp.host syntax for their username.  So clearly it is possible to implement a proxy that does what you want.  However, I don't think Frox does exactly what you want, because you want one subset of users with normal names to be sent to one server, and all users not in that subset to default to a honeypot instead.

It might be possible to do what you want using the Connection Translation feature of [ftp.proxy](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ftp.proxy), but I've no experience with which to say.